# Get object by key with certain value from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, key, nsdictionary

I have NSDictionary with objects. The NSDictionary is consist of json(You can see it below). I need to populate my table view with the name by id. And the id can repeat. It means I can have several "name" with id which is equal 0. I should get name by key with certain value from the dictionary. Here is my NSDictionary:

```
    {
        name = "smth1";
        id = 0;
    },
        {
        name = "smth2";
        id = 1;
    },
        {
        name = "smth3";
        id = 2;
    },
        {
        name = "smth4";
        id = 2;
    },
   ...
```

For example, I want to get value of key "name" where id is 2. Then I will get name = "smth3" and name = "smth4". Generally, I am trying to populate my table view component with the nested data. How can I do this? Any tips, ideas. Thank you.

Comment: You have `NSDictionary` of `NSDictionary`s, right?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov no I have only one NSDictionary.

Comment: But what is `name` and `id`? Is is properties of your model? What contain your `NSDictionary`?

Comment: lookd like u have an array of dictionaries. EIther you can enumerate thru all those objects and findout dic[@"id"] isEqualToString @"2"

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I have NSDictionary which contains json (you can see it below in the question).

Comment: `NSPredicate` could be a solution, enumerating the array of dictionary could be a solution, what have you tried?

Comment: Why you don't parse it to model to get array of models with needed properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you show an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary has 2 keys.

You could use the NSArray function `indexOfObjectPassingTest`. That code might look like this (starting from an NSArray) :

```
int idToFind = 2;
NSArray *dictArray = @[@{@"name": @"smth1",
                         @"id": @(0)},
                       
                       @{@"name": @"smth2",
                         @"id": @(1)},
                       
                       @{@"name": @"smth3",
                         @"id": @(2)}
                       ];


NSUInteger dictIndex = 
  [dictArray indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^BOOL(
    NSDictionary *dict, 
    NSUInteger idx, 
    BOOL *stop) {
       return [dict[@"id"] intValue] == idToFind;
  }];
if (dictIndex != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"Found id %d with name %@", idToFind, dictArray[dictIndex][@"name"]);
}
```

}

### EDIT:

If you need to match all of the items then you need to use the NSArray method `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`. That finds all the items in an array that match.

That code would look like this:

```
int idToFind = 2;
NSArray *dictArray = @[@{@"name": @"smth1",
                         @"id": @(0)},
                       
                       @{@"name": @"Fred",
                         @"id": @(2)},
                       
                       @{@"name": @"smth2",
                         @"id": @(1)},
                       
                       @{@"name": @"smth3",
                         @"id": @(2)},
                       ];
NSIndexSet *dictIndexes;
dictIndexes = 
  [dictArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: ^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict,
    NSUInteger idx,
    BOOL *stop) 
  {
    return [dict[@"id"] intValue] == idToFind;
  }];
 if (dictIndexes.count == 0) {
   NSLog(@"No matches found");
 }
 [dictIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger index, 
   BOOL * _Nonnull stop) 
 {
  NSLog(@"Found id=%@ with name \"%@\" at index %lu", 
    dictArray[index][@"id"], 
    dictArray[index][@"name"], 
    index);
 }];
```

Both approaches above use methods that take a block. The block contains code that you write that returns a BOOL for the item(s) that match your desired search criteria.

Search/sort methods that take blocks are very flexible because you can provide any code you want to do the matching/comparison.

The `indexOfObjectPassingTest` method searches for a single object in your array and stops when it finds the first match.

In contrast, the `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` function will match multiple items. It returns an `NSIndexSet`, a special class that's used to index into NSArrays.

There is a function enumerateIndexesUsingBlock that invokes a block of code for each index specified in the array.

We could also have used the method `objectsAtIndexes` to extract only the elements in the array that are listed in the resulting index set, and then used `for...in` to loop through the items. That code would look like this:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [dictArray objectsAtIndexes: dictIndexes];
for (NSDictionary *aDict in filteredArray) {
  NSLog(@"Found id=%@ with name \"%@\"", aDict[@"id"], aDict[@"name"]);
}
```

Note that this sort of thing is simpler and cleaner in Swift. We could use a `filter` statement on the array and provide a closure that selects items that match our search criteria

Comment: Thank you. Your answer worked. But it shows me only one "name" with id=0. I have several names with id=0. I updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Oh. You didn't say that. You can rewrite the code above to use the NSArray function indexesOfObjectsPassingTest, and then loop through the resulting `NSIndexSet`.